# RollControls: Where did they go?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to access RollControls in r58 as in r57. I cannot find any reference in the Migration pages. Any reason why they were removed from r58? Were they renamed or replaced?

Comment: *suggestion:* why don't you ask `three.js` developers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have been removed. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3153.

three.js r.58

Comment: It should have been written in the migration notes. There are just too many places that one has to look for changes to the API.

Comment: No. `RollControls` was one of the examples. It was not part of the library.